Cannot override CSS module style with style in global (or external) stylesheet in React / Next.js / React Native
I'm struggling to find a solution to this simple problem. I have a component which I, by default, style using a class from a *.module.css file. However, I want to override this style with one from a global stylesheet or some other style sheet, but I am failing to achieve this.
The reason I would like to do this is because I am creating a styled UI library that others can use. They will only download HelloWorld.tsx and HelloWorld.module.css (which supplies a default style for the background). Then they can override the background by supplying their own class when they use the component. So I was just trying to figure out what the best way to go about that is.
See example below:
// HelloWorld.tsx
import styles from './HelloWorld.module.css'

export default function HelloWorld({className}) {
    return <div className={`${styles.Container} ${className}`}>Hello world</div>;
}

/* HelloWorld.module.css */
.Container {
  background-color: green; /* a default style for the component to be overridden by users */
}

/* global.css */
.danger-container {
    background-color: red;
}

I then want to use the component as follows:
<HelloWorld className='danger-container' />

but the local style is not being overridden and the container remains green.
The only way I can override it is using !important but I have been told that it is bad practice to do this and would rather the users of the library not have to use !important to override my default styles.
Please assist me on what the best way to go about this is.
Thank you in advance.

Your two CSS statement have the same level of specificity so whichever statement comes last in the cascade wins. In your case this is the .Container. If you want .danger-container to override .Container then you will need for it to be more specific. There are several ways to do this. Here are a few:


.danger-container {/* 0,1,0 */
    background-color: red;
}

.Container.danger-container {/* 0,2,0 */
    background-color: blue;
}

body .danger-container[class] {/* 0,2,1 */
    background-color: pink;
}

.Container {/* 0,1,0 */
    background-color: green;
}
<div class='Container danger-container'>Hello world</div>



Another way would be to give your element an ID since ID's trump classes in terms of specificity.


#danger-container {/* 1,0,0 */
    background-color: orange;
}

.Container {/* 0,1,0 */
    background-color: green;
}
<div class='Container' id='danger-container'>Hello world</div>



Some resources to help you learn about CSS Specificity:

CSS Specificity Calculator
MDN Web Docs - Specificity
Web.dev - Learn Specificity

Update.
Based on you comment, I think you should consider CSS Cascade Layers. Cascade layers allow you to group your CSS into 'layers' ordered by priority. Declarations in higher priority layers take prescience over those in the lower regardless of the declarations specificity (mostly, see: https://css-tricks.com/css-cascade-layers/)


/* Establish a layer order, from lowest to highest priority */
@layer default, modules, theme;

/* import stylesheets into a layer, eg: */
@import url('HelloWorld.module.css') layer(modules);

/* or add styles to a specific layer, eg: */
@layer theme {
  /* high layer priority, despite same specificity */
  .container { 
    color: orange;
    border:1px solid orange;
  }
}

/* un-layered styles have the highest priority... */
.container {
  color: green;
}

/* last in the cascade but in a lower priority layer so still wont override unlayered styles or those in a higher-priority layer */
@layer default {
  .container { 
    color: red;
    border:1px solid red;
  }
}
<div class="container">Hello world</div>



Browser Support for CSS Cascade Layers

Hey @Moob. Thanks for the response. I would like to keep the definition of .Container in the *.module.css file and the definition of danger-container in global.css. The main idea is that I'm a writing a React UI library that others can use and they will only  download HelloWorld.tsx and HelloWorld.module.css which supplies a default style. Then they can override the background by supplying their own class when they use the component. So I was just trying to figure out what the best way to go about that is.

@TommyWolfheart Probably too late to be any use to you but I have updated my answer to include an example solution using CSS Cascade Layers.

No, still working on it so it's definitely very useful. I'll give it a shot and report back. Thanks.
